# Disable suexec for specific part of an Apache vhost

Tags: apache, cgi, suexec

In an Apache 2.4 vHost, I want to use CGI with the default user (www-data), as the script is located outside of suexec's document root. Additionally, I want to execute a script with suexec (via ScriptAlias). Both tasks work fine (the CGI one with the SuexecUserGroup Line disabled, the ScriptAlias one with it enabled) on their own, but are mutually exclusive right now. I wondered whether it is possible to disable suexec for the CGI part of my vHost conf.

How would one do that?

Context: I want to access Gitolite3 via Gitweb (→ CGI) and Smart HTTP (→ suexec).

Answer (score 0):

Now, after even more research, I assume that the thing I want to achieve in my question is not possible.

In my specific scenario, I added the www-data user to the gitolite3 group and gave the gitolite-shell the group execute permission. Then, I could remove the Suexec statement in my vHost and everything works.